# iOS 5.1 simulator Twitter sign in issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator, xcode4.4

I'm started to develop some application whit Twitter integration, but when trying sign in to Twitter ... this happen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agdn5.png

every time, I tried some different accounts. 
I'm on Macbook 2011 , OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), Xcode 4.4 (4F250), iOS Simulator 5.1 (272.21)

I'll be happy of any ideas, because after researching ,didn't find anything :(

Comment: The issue is in the ios simulator, before run the app I need sign in   to twitter

Comment: Can you log into the website with these accounts? It can't honestly be an issue with the Simulator - there's nothing new about the 5.1 simulator.

Comment: Yes, I tried , it's fine, it's no account problem that is checked . I think it's Mountain Lion and/or Xcode 4.4 bug , look at this https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Mountain Lion and/or Xcode 4.4 issue/bug!

Read here https://devforums.apple.com/message/705937#705937
And here  https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug occurring in Mac OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion).

It's probably because Mountain Lion has a native `Social.framework` and the developer tools, I assume are using these, and therefore the `Twitter.framework` isn't being used, so when you try to login to twitter with the simulator on iOS 5.x it can't use `Social.framework` and the system isn't using `Twitter.framework` correctly as a fallback.

Anyhow, here is the official word on it:

> When using the iOS 6.1 SDK on OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion), if you use
>   the iOS 5.0 or iOS 5.1 “Legacy SDK” in iOS Simulator, you will not be
>   able to sign in to Twitter via the Settings pane, and
>   Twitter.framework will not work correctly. If you need to test Twitter
>   features, you will need to choose either the iOS 6.1 or iOS 6.0
>   Simulator run destination, or test with iOS 5.x on a device. These
>   problems do not occur when running Simulator on OS X v10.7 (Lion).

Source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_1/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012869) (Social section)

Comment: I would suggest you drop support for iOS 5.

Comment: May be in nearest future :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a problem with a server somewhere, but the only other explanation is something wrong with the simulator. The best advice I think I can give you is to try reset content and settings in the simulator, reboot your Mac and if that doesn't help you may need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: There is reported that issue may be is Xcode 4.4 bug ...    https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850